# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0 after using prepared statement

Tags: c++, prepared-statement, mysql

I am using MySQL and a prepared statement to insert a `BLOB` record (jpeg image).  After executing the prepared statement, I issue a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and it returns 0.

In my code I put a breakpoint after the execution command and in a MySQL command (monitor) window, I issue the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` and it returns zero.

In the MySQL command (monitor) window, I issue an SQL statement to select all the IDs and the last (only) inserted ID is 1 (one).

I am using:

- Server version: 5.1.46-community
  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Visual Studio 2008, version 9.
- MySQL Connector C++ 1.0.5

My table description:

```
mysql> describe picture_image_data;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Image_Data | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Image_Data    | mediumblob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.19 sec)
```

Results using MySQL monitor:

```
mysql> select ID_Image_Data
    -> from picture_image_data;
+---------------+
| ID_Image_Data |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The Prepared statement:

```
INSERT INTO Picture_Image_Data
(ID_Image_Data, Image_Data)
VALUES
    (?,
       ?);
```

The results above show that the ID_Image_Data field is one, but the LAST_INSERT_ID is zero.  The table is created before this statement is executed, so this is the only record in the table.

---

### Edit:

I am setting the ID field to zero and the next field to a C++ `std::istream *`.  According to the [MySQL Manual Page for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

*The value of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is not changed if you set the AUTO_INCREMENT column of a row to a non-“magic” value (that is, **a value that is not NULL and not 0**).*

The LAST_INSERT_ID() should return 1 since the ID value in the prepared statement is 0.

---

Do I need to make a prepared statement for fetching LAST_INSERT_ID?

*{Searching the web showed to use a custom MySQL API, but that used PHP and futher comments said it needs another connection).*

Comment: Last_insert_id is connection specific, where are you executing the prepared insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issues is with the MySQL C++ connector.

1. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns 0 when
   the ID field is null, *explicit*
   insert.
2. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns 0 when
   the ID field is not specified,
   *implicit* insert.

I tried insert the `BLOB` (JPEG image) from the command line (monitor), and it works:

```
mysql> describe picture_image_data;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID_Image_Data | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Image_Data    | mediumblob       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
mysql> PREPARE blob_stmt
    ->     FROM 'INSERT INTO picture_image_data (ID_Image_Data, Image_Data) VALUES (?, LOAD_FILE(?))';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> SET @id = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @c = 'KY_hot_brown_picture.jpg';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXECUTE blob_stmt USING @id, @c;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For now, the workaround is to use SQL statements to insert the BLOB with a prepared statement rather than the MySQL C++ Connector API.

Answer (score 5):

LAST_INSERT_ID would only work for auto generated primary key, that was created on auto_increment field. In your case, it looks like you are supplying the id explicitly, so last insert id is not set.

This is explicit:

```
mysql> insert into test (id, name) VALUES (5, 'test 2');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is implicit:

```
mysql> insert into test (name) values ('test');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
+------------------+
| LAST_INSERT_ID() |
+------------------+
|                3 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I am supplying an ID field of zero.  According to a manual page, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id, *The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() is not changed if you set the AUTO_INCREMENT column of a row to a non-“magic” value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0).*  So it should work.

Comment: Hmm, you're right... I just tried that, and it worked in mysql console. I'm not very familiar with C++ connector... But since you're in control of a statement, you can fix it just by removing the insert to that column...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect issuing a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` on the mysql command line client to give you the last inserted value that was generated in your C++ code.

LAST_INSERT_ID() gives you the last autogenerated ID on the given connection. Obviously your C++ program and the mysql client uses 2 different connections to the mysql server.

(and LAST_INSERT_ID() should be used after an INSERT too, don't have other SQL statements inbetwwen the INSERT and SELECTLAST_INSERT_ID())

Comment: In the code, the return value from LAST_INSERT_ID() is zero.  I will change the code to use only select statements and not the prepared statement API.

Comment: When I insert a record into a table using the program without a prepared statement, I can check the `LAST_INSERT_ID` via the command line and the result is correct.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews You cannot rely on that being the case. It's still quite unknown whether your problem is doing this in code, or if your actuall issue is running SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() in a terminal on another connection - which isn't supposed to work anyway