# Function last_insert_id return 0

Tags: mysql

I have promlems:

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE auto(id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,num int);
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.40 sec)

    mysql> INSERT INTO auto VALUES(1,1);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.51 sec)

    mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM auto;
    +------------------+
    | LAST_INSERT_ID() |
    +------------------+
    |                0 |
```

**Why return 0 ?**

Comment: You don't need `FROM auto`, it's used by issuing `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Comment: SOrry....Asnswer :LAST_INSERT_ID would only work for auto generated primary key, that was created on auto_increment field. In your case, it looks like you are supplying the id explicitly, so last insert id is not set. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124546/select-last-insert-id-returns-0-after-using-prepared-statement?rq=1